# Removing toc in epub

Tags: html, tableofcontents

I would like the red mark in the pic to be removed and only the green mark to appear in my ebook. Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: You can use CSS and set the first child to be visible and hide the other children.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: I recommend you share what you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: They should share what they tried. It looks like they are looking for an easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the code you want. You can make it in other different ways too.
If you post your code in your question it helps others to understand what do you want.

```
<style>
    #myHeadings li {
        display: none;
    }

    #myHeadings li:nth-child(1) {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div style="width: 400px; position:absolute; margin: auto; padding: 10px;">
    <Ol id="myHeadings">
        <li>Chapter 1. The princess i reased with my own hands</li>
        <li>Chapter 2. Weakness is there</li>
        <li>Chapter 3. I dont Need a Price</li>
        <li>Chapter 4. Epilogue: Contractor&apos;s Smile, Dragon&apos;s Defilement</li>
    </Ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can now figure out how to do this^^